# Android BLE scanresult is different from iOS

Tags: java, android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I implemented BLE on my android app for communication with 1 peripheral device using same thing. I faced an issue with understanding how it works. After connecting with the device, i receive an `byte[]` with value `[2, 1, 6, 8, -1, 97, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. This should contain `OriginId (2 bytes)`, `ProductId (4 bytes)` & `Location (1 byte)`. I've tried several ways to decode, split that array, but cannot get same result as iOS get's via their `Bluetooth Core`. Any idea how I could parse that array to get the following results:

```
All advertisement data: 61030000000000
bluetoothSIG: 6103
productId: 00000000
location: 00
```

Comment: when you say connect to device, are you getting its read and write characteristics?

Comment: otherwise, before connecting to the device, what byte data do you see?